# Error after changing the primary key to from PKID to UserID

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldatasource

I have a ASP.NET/VB that had a GridView to display a list of users from the Users table.

I changed the primary key column name in the database from PKID to UserID and updated all the old references to PKID in the declarations and code behind. I also deleted the WebsiteCache folder which held the visual studio cache of the website.

When I drop a new SQLDatasource on the page and try to configure it, the old PKID is still there but when I connect via Server Explorer the UserID column is shown as expected.

Is there another cache or something I'm missing in all this?

The error is:

UserID is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table DefaultView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to refresh the schema in the Server Explorer? Also, if you have added a connection, just try to remove or refresh it before adding your SqlDataSource.

Comment: I did try the refresh from the datasource and from the grid itself, no luck. I created a new page dropped a new SQLDatasource and new gridview. no problem. I could just do that again but I've already customized the existing datasource. VS is doing something to cache this stuff but I don't know where